# Cast error when taking screenshot in flutter

Tags: flutter

When trying to take a screenshot I get a cast error

```
type 'RenderStack' is not a subtype of type 'RenderRepaintBoundary' in type cast
```

I see other examples of people doing the same thing. But I don't understand why it is throwing this for me?

```
var ro = _repaintKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary;
try {
  boundary = ro as RenderRepaintBoundary;
}catch(e){
  print('takeScreenShot - error: ' + e.toString());
  return;
}
```

I broke out the cast as a separate line to isolate the issue.
I can see that RenderPaintBoundary is not a child of RenderStack
but docs say findRenderObject() returns a RenderObject? not a RenderStack.
I am using Flutter version 2.10.2

Comment: Can you show where `_repaintKey` is used?

Comment: class variable
GlobalKey _repaintKey = GlobalKey();

Comment: Thanks, but I meant more in the Widget tree.

Comment: That is only place _repaintKey is used, I get a valid currentContext when I examine it at run time.

Comment: You need to assign this key to your `RepaintBoundary` widget so that the render object returned is a `RenderRepaintBoundary`

Comment: So, I realized I didn't have a RepaintBoundry defined anywhere.
Added a RepaintBoundy around my body

body: RepaintBoundary(
              child:body(),),

this caused the findRendObject to still return a RenderStack, but the parent of that stack was a RepaintBoundry. 
That let me call
RenderObject ro = _repaintKey.currentContext.findRenderObject().parent;
which is a RenderRepaintBoundry
and allows me to grab the image!
Still seems like something is not right, but it works.
I tried adding the _repaint key to the RepaintBoundry, but I got a duplicate global key issue.

Comment: Hard to say without the code/error, but it sounds like the key is reused somewhere/somehow. It would probably work without having to access the parent if your key is used for `RepaintBoundry` directly.